# TestScheduler not working while testing specific usecase

Tags: android, testing, junit, kotlin, rx-java2

I am testing single use-case. but test observer will not emit any thing in test environment.

- even if i change `subscribeOn()` from `Schedulers.newThread()` to
  `TestScheduler()` still test fail. i am confuse. and i don't know what
  i am doing wrong here?
- if i remove `subscribeOn`,`observeOn` method then test pass successfully.then
  what is the actual use of `TestScheduler()` ?

following are the `UseCase.kt` file

```
abstract class UseCase<T>(val postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread) {

    abstract fun buildUseCaseBuilder(): Observable<T>

    /**
     * execute method for observables
     */
    open fun execute(): Observable<T> {
        return buildUseCaseBuilder()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler())
    }
}
```

following the test class with above class under test

```
class UseCaseTest {

    val postExecutionThread=Mockito.mock(PostExecutionThread::class.java)
    val result: String="test"
    val testObserver=TestObserver<String>()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        _when(postExecutionThread.getScheduler()).thenReturn(TestScheduler())
    }

    @Test
    fun `test execute method of use case`() {
        println(" thread type ${postExecutionThread.getScheduler()}")

        //test fail
        //java.lang.AssertionError: Value count differs; Expected: 1 [test], Actual: 0 [] (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0)
        TestUseCase(postExecutionThread).execute().test()
                .assertResult(result)

        //subscriber not print any thing
        TestUseCase(postExecutionThread).execute().subscribe{
            println("called $it")
        }
    }

    inner class TestUseCase(postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread?) : UseCase<String>(postExecutionThread!!) {
        override fun buildUseCaseBuilder(): Observable<String> {
            return Observable.just(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that your tests are being run on a thread other than those, that you specify using `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()`. What you want is make tests and the tested code run synchronously on the same thread, regardless what is specified inside `subscribeOn()`/`observeOn()`.

You can achieve that using custom [`@Rule`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html) like [this one](https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate/blob/master/app/src/test/java/uk/co/ribot/androidboilerplate/util/RxSchedulersOverrideRule.java):

```
/**
 * This rule registers Handlers for RxJava and RxAndroid to ensure that subscriptions
 * always subscribeOn and observeOn Schedulers.trampoline().
 * Warning, this rule will reset RxAndroidPlugins and RxJavaPlugins before and after each test so
 * if the application code uses RxJava plugins this may affect the behaviour of the testing method.
 */
public class RxSchedulersOverrideRule implements TestRule {

    private final Function<Callable<Scheduler>, Scheduler> mRxAndroidSchedulersHook =
            new Function<Callable<Scheduler>, Scheduler>() {
                @Override
                public Scheduler apply(@NonNull Callable<Scheduler> schedulerCallable)
                        throws Exception {
                    return getScheduler();
                }
            };

    private final Function<Scheduler, Scheduler> mRxJavaImmediateScheduler =
            new Function<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
                @Override
                public Scheduler apply(@NonNull Scheduler scheduler) throws Exception {
                    return getScheduler();
                }
            };

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(mRxAndroidSchedulersHook);

                RxJavaPlugins.reset();
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(mRxJavaImmediateScheduler);
                RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(mRxJavaImmediateScheduler);

                base.evaluate();

                RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
                RxJavaPlugins.reset();
            }
        };
    }

    public Scheduler getScheduler() {
        return Schedulers.trampoline();
    }

}
```

With this code you intercept all the schedulers and make everything to work on [`trampoline()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#trampoline--) scheduler.

Now just add following `@Rule` to your test:

```
    public class MyTestClass {

        @Rule
        public final RxSchedulersOverrideRule mOverrideSchedulersRule = new RxSchedulersOverrideRule();

        @Test
        public void someTest() {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes you are right i just add trampoline() and test works.thanks. then what is actual use of TestScheduler ?

Comment: `TestScheduler` would come handy when you want to advance time, for example you have a stream, that will emit a value in 10 second. Instead of waiting 10 seconds inside your test you would like to **advance** 10 seconds and verify that the value is emitted. See [this](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/testing-asynchronous-rxjava-code-using-mockito-8ad831a16877) blog post for example use-case.

Comment: thanks i got it. i am injecting subscribeOn and observeOn with trampoline. i don't wont to add RxAndroidPlugins dependency in my domain layer thank you so much. appreciate your help.

Comment: You saved my day. I passed `trampoline()` as well and worked!